# Azure devops does not fail when command execution fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

In one of my builds: https://dev.azure.com/ericmjl/Tutorials/_build/results?buildId=660&view=logs

I notice the following problem. The execution of the `nbconvert` command does not fail when a code cell errors out.

I'm not sure if this is an nbconvert problem or an Azure problem, but my first instinct was to ask: is there a way to ensure that Azure fails when the `nbconvert` command encounters a failed cell?

Comment: If you want a single command to fail, let it return a non-zero code. If you want multiple commands in a script to fail, that script must return a non-zero code too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it gives a non-zero exit code. Specifically for cell execution errors it will usually give an exit code of 1.

However, there are some kernel sin question does not send back an error when an exception occurs (some Spark kernels don't do this), which is against what the spec asks for, then nbconvert doesn't know there was an error. I know of 3 or 4 kernels that behave this way and are mostly unmaintained kernels for which no one is fixing issues anymore.

Based on reading your build I see the correct error and exception being raised. However, I think your script is only looking for errors on the last line of your template. You may need `&&` at the end of [each line before](https://github.com/ericmjl/bayesian-stats-modelling-tutorial/blob/master/.azure-pipelines/templates/nb-docs-nix.yml#L3-L5) to halt execution upon the first error encountered.